# how to avoid "Added cscope database" on vim launch

Tags: vim, configuration

I autoload cscope.out from the current directory when i launch `vim` but everytime I launch  `vim`, I get an annoying print that may read:

```
$ vim
Added cscope database /workingpath/cscope.out
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I avoid this to save that extra `ENTER` keystroke?
My `.vimrc` looks like:

```
" Pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags() " generate helptags for everything in 'runtimepath'
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
filetype plugin indent on

set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set autoindent

nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>

if has('cscope')
    set cscopetag cscopeverbose
    if has('quickfix')
        set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
    endif

    cnoreabbrev csa cs add
    cnoreabbrev csf cs find
    cnoreabbrev csk cs kill
    cnoreabbrev csr cs reset
    cnoreabbrev css cs show
    cnoreabbrev csh cs help

    command -nargs=0 Cscope cs add $VIMSRC/src/cscope.out $VIMSRC/src
endif

" g:CCTreeCscopeDb = "./cscope.out"
set autochdir
```

Comment: I might be missing something as I can't see where you're actually doing `cscope add` or `Cscope`, but... `:help :silent` should be able to help you.

Comment: @Amadan wouldn't that be the line: `command -nargs=0 Cscope cs add $VIMSRC/src/cscope.out $VIMSRC/src` ?

Comment: That line defines the command `Cscope`; I can't see where it is invoked.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the following to your .vimrc:

```
set nocscopeverbose
```

FYI: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'cscopeverbose'